# Is my requested form correctly saved into a JSON api?

Tags: python, json, api

I´m creating a JSON API (saved in a JSON file) using Flask, Python 2.7 and REST requests.
My problem is that I can only access all the data that is saved in a JSON file. I want to be able to only see one object from the array (When I want to edit the data, for a PUT request), with data['title'], which I does not work right now. Which makes me think that perhaps I´m not saving the requested form correctly?
Any idea where it is not right when I save the data with post? Or if there is another problem?
Appreciate all help given!

```
    @app.route('/articleAdded', methods = ['POST'])
def added():
    '''Adds new articles'''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.form['title']
        author = request.form['author']
        text = request.form['text']

        article = {'title' : title, 'author' : author, 'text' : text}
        articles.append(article)

        try:
            with open("articles.json", "w") as json_File:
                new_art = json.dump(articles, json_File, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
                json_File.close()
            return render_template('articleAdded.html', title = title, author = author, text = text)
        except:
            return render_template('errorHandler.html'), 404

    @app.route('/edit/<string:title>', methods=['GET'])
    def edit(title):
        '''shows specific aticle'''
        try:
            with open("articles.json", 'r') as article_file:
                data = json.load(article_file)
                print data['title']
                if title == data['title'] :
                    print "hello"
                    return render_template('editArticle.html', data = data, title = title)
                else:
                    print "Something went wrong!"
                data.close()
        except:
            return render_template('errorHandler.html'), 404
```

Comment: Can you run your program and tell us what you are getting for the print statements or does it not even compile? One quick problem I see is that in the first method you append something to the variable `articles` that has never been declared.

Comment: Articles is a global list. The code above does not present all of my code. It runs without error. However, the problem is that when I open my Json file with the GET request I can only print the whole object, so if I have added three articles, all of those articles are printed. I want to be able to only print one of those three articles. Which I think you should be able to do, just by writing data["title"] (if I want the title). But this doesn´t work, so I thought there might be a problem with how I´m adding the articles?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code comes from where you are placing the return statement in your first block of code. When you do a return, it immediately ends the method you are in regardless of whether or not it is in a loop. You may want to try something like this instead:

```
@app.route('/api/articles', methods=['GET'])
def show_articles():
    '''Opens dictionary and returns all users as json format'''
    try:
        with open('articles.json') as open_file:
            json_ret = [jsonify({'article': article}) for article in open_file]
            return json_ret
    except:
        return render_template('errorHandler.html'), 404
```

This will give it to you in the form of a list of jsonified objects which I'm assuming is what you were trying to do originally.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! Saw that I was uploading the wrong code, wanted to show the post request. Sorry! But thanks for discovering my mistake. :) Do you have any idea why I can´t see only one object and only the whole list?